# Best Practice: function return value or byref output parameters?

Tags: function, return-value, return

I have a function called FindSpecificRowValue that takes in a datatable and returns the row number that contains a particular value. If that value isn't found, I want to indicate so to the calling function.

Is the best approach to:

1. Write a function that returns false if not found, true if found, and the found row number as a byref/output parameter, or
2. Write a function that returns an int and pass back -999 if the row value isn't found, the row number if it is?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Personally I would not do either with that method name.

I would instead make two methods:

```
TryFindSpecificRow
FindSpecificRow
```

This would follow the pattern of Int32.Parse/TryParse, and in C# they could look like this:

```
public static Boolean TryFindSpecificRow(DataTable table, out Int32 rowNumber)
{
    if (row-can-be-found)
    {
        rowNumber = index-of-row-that-was-found;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        rowNumber = 0; // this value will not be used anyway
        return false;
    }
}

public static Int32 FindSpecificRow(DataTable table)
{
    Int32 rowNumber;


    if (TryFindSpecificRow(table, out rowNumber))
        return rowNumber;
    else
        throw new RowNotFoundException(String.Format("Row {0} was not found", rowNumber));
}
```

---

**Edit:** Changed to be more appropriate to the question.

Comment: This is a nice way to go, especially with the familiar syntax of TryParse

Comment: Are 2 functions really necessary? why not look for the rowNumber within FindSpecificRow, throwing the exception if !row-can-be-found.

Comment: Well, it depends. If the function is expected to succeed in almost all cases, I would only implement the one, FindSpecificRow, throwing an exception if for some odd reason it couldn't find the row after all. However, if I expect the request to sometimes fail, or in other words, if I expect the calling code to sometimes want to call me and expect a negative result, I would implement them both. Not throwing an exception is cheaper than doing it.

Comment: @Junier Sometimes programers require the first option, sometimes the second option. What can be done, in order to avoid duplicated code is to have one function call the other as the main answer does

Answer (score 3):

functions that fail should throw exceptions.

If failure is part of the expected flow then returning an out of band value is OK, except where you cannot pre-determine what an out-of-band value would be, in which case you have to throw an exception.

If I had to choose between your options I would choose option 2, but use a constant rather than -999...

Comment: uh-oh - exceptions as exceptional behaviour war coming... **dives for cover**

Answer (score 3):

You could also define return value as [Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) and return Nothing if nothing found.

Answer (score 2):

I would choose option 2. Although I think I would just use -1 not -999.

Richard Harrison is right that a named constant is better than a bare -1 or -999.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with 2, or some other variation where the return value indicates whether the value was found.

It seems that the value of the row the function returns (or provides a reference to) already indicates whether the value was found. If a value was not found, then it seems to make no sense to provide a row number that doesn't contain the value, so the return value should be -1, or Null, or whatever other value is suitable for the particular language. Otherwise, the fact that a row number was returned indicates the value was found.

Thus, there doesn't seem to be a need for a separate return value to indicate whether the value was found. However, type 1 might be appropriate if it fits with the idioms of the particular language, and the way function calls are performed in it.

Answer (score 1):

Go with 2) but return -1 (or a null reference if returning a reference to the row), that idiom is uses extensively (including by by .nets indexOf (item) functions), it's what I'd probably do.

BTW -1 is more acceptable and widly used "magic number" than -999, thats the only reason why it's "correct" (quotes used there for a reason).

However much of this has to do with what you expect. Should the item always be in there, but you just don't know where? In that case return the index normally, and throw an error/exception if it's not there.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the item might not be there, and that's an okay condition. It's an error trap for unselected values in a GridView that binds to a datatable.

Answer (score 0):

Another few possibilities not yet mentioned:

```
// Method 1: Supports covariance; can return default<T> on failure.
T TryGetThing(ref bool success); 

// Method 2: Does not support covariance, but may allow cleaner code in some cases
// where calling code would use some particular value in in case of failure.
T TryGetThing(T DefaultValue);

// Method 3: Does not support covariance, but may allow cleaner code in some cases
// where calling code would use some particular value in case of failure, but should
// not take the time to compute that value except when necessary.
T TryGetThing(Func<T> AlternateGetMethod);

// Method 4: Does support covariance; ErrorMethod can throw if that's what should
// happen, or it can set some flag which is visible to the caller in some other way.
T TryGetThing(Action ErrorMethod);
```

The first approach is the reverse of the method Microsoft developed in the days before support existed for covariant interfaces.  The last is in some ways the most versatile, but is likely to require the creation of a couple of new GC object instances (e.g. a closure and a delegate) each time it's used.